# Creating Python dictionary of classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm sure there's an answer to this question somewhere on SO, but I can't seem to find the right search terms to ferret it out.

Source file layout:

```
./mycode.py
./protocols/__init__py (empty)
./protocols/prot1.py
./protocols/prot2.py
./protocols/prot3.py
```

./protocols/prot1.py:

```
class Prot1:

    @classmethod
    def getAddress(cls, data):
        return f(data)
```

Similar for Prot2 and Prot3, but the return value is calculated differently in each class.

mycode.py:

```
import protocols

self.protocolClasses = {
    "1"  : Prot1,
    "2"  : Prot2,
    "3"  : Prot3
}

protocol = "1"  # just for the example
f = self.protocolClasses[protocol].getAddress(somedata)
```

That seems right to me, but Python gives an error:

```
NameError: global name 'Prot1' is not defined
```

The line number referenced is:

```
    "1"  : Prot1,
```

What am I missing?

Edit:  If I use the following syntax:

```
"1"  : protocols.prot1.Prot1,
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'prot1'
```

If I use:

```
"1"  : protocols.Prot1,
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Prot1'
```

Comment: what is `Prot1`? You mean `protocols.prot1.Prot1`. You can also go with `from protocols.prot1 import Prot1` if you're going to use it in more places.

Comment: I meant the class Prot1, defined in the file ./protocols/prot1.py.  Is the capitalization messing me up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having directory structure as yours you have to fix imports.

Here is what will work:

```
from protocols.prot1 import Prot1
from protocols.prot2 import Prot2
from protocols.prot3 import Prot3

self.protocolClasses = {
    "1"  : Prot1,
    "2"  : Prot2,
    "3"  : Prot3
}

protocol = "1"  # just for the example
f = self.protocolClasses[protocol].getAddress(somedata)
```

Or you can use `./protocols/__init__py` and add next lines in it:

```
from prot1 import Prot1
from prot2 import Prot2 
from prot3 import Prot3
```

This way you will be able to do imports like:

```
from protocols import Prot1, Prot2, Prot3
```

Now why is that?

It's because `protocols` is a Python package (by having `__init__.py` file in it) and `prot1`, `prot2`, `prot3` are Python modules. In those modules you have defined classes. That is why you need to use full namespace i.e. `protocols.prot1.Prot1` or `from protocols.prot1 import Prot1`.

Comment: Thanks!  That nailed it.  I wonder if I would have been better off not having the __init__.py file and just imported the file contents?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you remove `protocols/__init__.py` you will not be able to `from protocols.prot1 import Prot1` at all. Alternative is to have `protocols.py` instead of directory, and have all classes defined in it.

Comment: I see.  I really wanted to break them up into individual files because the amount of code was growing rapidly.  So what I have now is working, and I'll stick with it.  Thanks again!